# How are we able to study Quantum phenomena in Particle physics using relativitity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, particle-physics, collision

When we look at at a relativistic collision like compton scattering or decay of the Higgs particle, we treat the colliding particles literally as particles following a definite trajectory and scattering with some definite angle. These collisions are treated using relativistic conservation of energy and momentum.

But in quantum mechanics, particles are described by their state vector in the Hilbert space, and do not collapse to be localized particles unless their positions are measured. My question is then: how can we treat these collisions like they are billiard balls, when in reality the particles are wavefunctions and only measurement should result in particles being observed?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146145/discussion-on-question-by-sam-jefferson-how-are-we-able-to-study-quantum-phenome); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5):

Other answers have given some valuable considerations, especially in the context of the specific question being asked - about how we can do relativistic conservation of energy and momentum to determine some aspects of a particle's motion.

Indeed, if you are going to produce some particles in a collision or decay, the produced particles conserve energy and momentum. So despite there being many possible outcomes described by quantum field theory, all of those outcomes have the same total energy and momentum (within the uncertainty of the initial state, which is highly well-defined by either the accelerator, or the fact that lifetimes are much longer than $1/m$ in units where $c=\hbar=1$).

However, these considerations leave us with a completely valid concern about how we transition from a calculation in QFT to clearly observable particles on well defined classical-looking trajectories.
[image]
There are other aspects of a particle's motion, like the moment that an unstable particle decays and the angle that produced particles are sent, which are not determined by conserved quantities, and QFT describes as different possible outcomes of a measurement on a wavefunction. **And I don't know the full answer**, but I'll write this answer to stimulate what I consider to be a more interesting part of the conversation.

The first step is that one needs to understand that protons in a beam that is soon to collide with another beam are in a quantum state with a wavepacket that is much larger than the distance between protons. Roughly speaking, imagine the two incoming protons as being in wavepackets that look like this:
[image]

And so for some time and some region of space, the two protons can be thought of as large plane waves that overlap. And this is the framework from which we do calculations in QFT - incoming and outgoing particles are described as infinitely big plane waves. We also find, by the way, that probabilities of creating certain outgoing particles can be described by "cross sections," eliminating any need to consider the precise shape of the wavepacket, except when discussing the uncertainty of incoming momenta. It should be emphasized that despite the visual appearance of Feynman diagrams looking like they might describe particles on linear trajectories, Feynman diagrams are just a calculation tool for finding the cross section for certain initial incoming plane waves evolving into certain final outgoing plane waves.

**here is where I get speculative and invite debate**

So after the particles have collided, QFT tell us that there are spherically symmetric wavepackets (or not spherically symmetric and instead described by some angular distribtuion). Here red/blue represent the part of the total-sytem-wavefunction which represents the possibility that the two protons didn't interact at all, and green represents the part of the wavefunction showing that they might have destroyed eachother and created a new particle which has a $\sin^2\theta$ angular distribution:

[image]

How we then transition to discrete particles on classical trajectories on is more or less the same question as "what is a measurement in quantum mechanics," and the answer, at least in many worlds interpretation, is decoherence. Eventually different sections of this spherically symmetric wave packet encounter things like the walls of the beampipe, background gas, or even pieces of the detector. They accumulate random phases from these interactions, and they loose the ability to interfere with each other. Then the experimental result, as seen by an outside observer (who isn't able to measure the entire wavefunction of the universe), is only one of these different decohered possibilities. Why we specifically collapse to a classical trajectory is called [the Mott problem (wiki link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mott_problem) (thanks to the commenter for pointing out this step in the logic). Essentially, although the probability that a detector element is struck remains spherically symmetric, the mutual probability that two detector elements are both struck is zero unless both detector elements are along a classical trajectory for the particle.

However, one piece of evidence that a superposition is, in fact, initially created in a collision is the phenomenon of particle oscillations. For example, here a superposition of $B_1$ and $B_2$ particles is created in the collision, and whether we are in a state $B_0=B_1+B_2$ or $\bar{B}_0=B_1-B_2$ determines what we decay into. The initial state evolves with time like $B_1e^{-im_1t}+B_2e^{-im_2t}$ (units where $c=\hbar=1$), and since these masses are different, the decay products oscillate over time:

[image]

An obvious requirement for this phenomenon is that the wavepackets produced in the collision remain overlapping - so for example the $B_1$ and the $B_2$ must have nearly the same mass and the same charge so they remain on the same path. This is, for example, why we don't see interference between the creation of charged and uncharged pions, or between the creation of neutral pions and neutrons.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [the Mott problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mott_problem). Briefly, Mott considered how quantum mechanics is able to generate straight particle trajectories in bubble chambers given a spherical wave function. The resolution involves considering the state of the detector in addition to the state of the particle.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. I've added that to the answer (which replaced what was previously the weakest part of the answer)

Answer (score 2):

The momenta and energies of the photons, electrons, higgses and so forth are    indeed defined to high accuracy and conserved. Their positions and times are not so sharply specified.  (Not on the relevant microscopic scale, though they may seem quite small to us humans.)  Heisenberg is satisfied by $\Delta x \Delta p > \hbar/2$ with a large $\Delta x$ and a small $\Delta p$, and similarly for energy and time.

Calculations are generally done describing particles as infinite plane waves - where the wavelength and frequency are exact, and the extent in position and time are infinite.

Answer (score 1):

> how can we treat these collisions like they are billiard balls,

They are not treated as billiard balls. In [scattering theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix), all the mathematics is based on co-variance to Lorenz transformations. The incoming and outgoing are wavefunctions,

Because the solutions have to be Lorenz covariant by construction one is able to use energy and momentum and angular momentum conservation for simple cases, as in the decay of a single particle, or conservation of energy and momentum in individual interactions.